# How can I return a TableView from a instance method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to add a TableView as a subview in my RootViewController.The TableView will come from another ViewController(`TableViewGeneratorController`) instance method.

So,What is the best way to do this?

I have created a TableViewGeneratorController it works fine as a standalone app. Then from my RootViewController I have created one instance of the TableViewGeneratorController and trying to call the instance method `prepareField`,which will return the TableView. I got the TableView but 
`numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not getting called.

## TableViewGeneratorController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewGeneratorController:UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *tableView;

}
@property(strong,nonatomic)UITableView *generatedTbleView;
- (UITableView *)prepareField;
@end
```

## TableViewGeneratorController.m

```
#import "TableViewGeneratorController.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface TableViewGeneratorController (){
}
@end

@implementation TableViewGeneratorController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (UITableView *)prepareField
{
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 500)];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [tableView reloadData];
    return tableView;

}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIndentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Yes";
    return cell;

}

@end
```

## RootViewController.m

Here I am trying to add the TableView as a subview.

```
TableViewGeneratorController *tableViewGeneratorController = [[TableViewGeneratorController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TableViewGeneratorController" bundle:nil];

UITableView *tv = [tableViewGeneratorController prepareField];

[self.view addSubview: tv];
```

What is the problem going on?

### Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is not really the proper way.

The immediate issue is that the `TableViewGeneratorController` instance that you create goes out of scope and is deallocated. This leaves the table view with not existing data source or delegate. A simple workaround is to assign the `TableViewGeneratorController` instance to an instance variable instead of a local variable.

But the proper solution is to embed the `TableViewGeneratorController` as a child controller of the root view controller.

Change `TableViewGeneratorController` to be a `UITableViewController` and get rid of the `prepareField` method.

Then when you create the `TableViewGeneratorController`, you add it as a child controller. See the docs for `UIViewController` for details.